# Which is better for PL/SQL, IF-ELSE OR SELECT DECODE IN ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

I was thinking of converting an if block into decode in my pl/sql function. Since we can't use decode directly in pl/sql, the plan is to use 'select decode() into variable from dual'. The existing if block is as follows:

```
if var1 = 'a' then
 var2 := 'x';

elseif var1 = 'b' then
 var2 := 'y';

else
 var2 := 'z';

end if;
```

the replacement decode could be:

```
 select decode(var1,'a','x','b','y','z') into var2 from dual;
```

The codeline could be reduced significantly(for similar larger blocks) with decode, but is it the better approach?

Comment: `CASE` works equally well and easy to understand. You can use `CASE` statement inplace of `DECODE`.

Comment: It's depends. But in your example it's bad idea. When sql is invoked from plsql oracle is changing context. (it's called context switching). And this is very popular performance mistake.

Comment: Better for an human to understand and maintain? to be ported to the next version of Oracle or another SQL product? for a parser to parse? for an optimizer to optimize?

Comment: In general, you should avoid DECODE. Use CASE instead, both in SQL and PL/SQL. And certainly inside PL/SQL, don't introduce a context switch to SQL when it is not needed. I wrote a blog post exploring options for conditional logic in PL/SQL. Might be useful here. http://stevenfeuersteinonplsql.blogspot.com/2017/10/plsql-101-writing-conditional-logic-in.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Oracle `PLSQL` block , 2 types of engines works. First `SQL` engine and another `PLSQL` engine. Whenever you write a `SQL` statement in a `PLSQL` block, the switching of engine takes place and this phenomena is called `Context` Switching. The more context switching the less performant application would be.

When you do :

```
if var1 = 'a' then
 var2 := 'x';

elseif var1 = 'b' then
 var2 := 'y';

else
 var2 := 'z';

end if;
```

The statement is evaluated in `PLSQL` engine and no context switching occurs. But when you do :

```
begin
select decode(var1,'a','x','b','y','z') into var2 from dual;
end;
```

`PLSQL` engine changes the control to SQL engine and context switching takes places. So this operation would make less performant.

Answer (score 1):

I think the first approach is better.

Since There's no need to produce an extra overhead through querying by `dual`, especially in large applications. I mean no need to apply database for a problem which could be resolved inside app. If you look at execution plan you'll see a cost value of 2, for querying `dual` table.

By the way, it's an extra load for networking between db and app server.